# How do I query this table to get this result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query

```
             select a.ord_no,a.item_no, a.line_no, b.from_item_no_1,b.qty_1, b.from_item_no_2,b.qty_2, b.from_item_no_3, b.qty_3,b.from_item_no_4,b.qty_4 from oeordlin_progview a
             join oepiklst_sql b on a.ord_no = b.ord_no and a.line_no = b.line_seq_no

             WHERE a.ord_type = 'O' 
             AND a.loc = '1' 
             AND a.picked_dt IS NULL
             AND a.line_item_status = 'FRFIN' 
             and a.ord_no = 410672
             order by a.line_no
```

which returns this result set

```
ord_no  item_no       line_no   from_item_no_1  qty_1   from_item_no_2  qty_2   from_item_no_3  qty_3   from_item_no_4  qty_4

00410672    12167           2   1               1.0000  2   5.0000  3   9.0000  4   13.0000
00410672    10              3   10000           1.0000  2   6.0000  3   12.0000 4   3.0000
00410672    2               4   1               1.0000  2   7.0000  3   2.0000  4   2.0000
```

How would I make it look like this for each item number

```
-------item_No 12167
ord_no, item_no, line_no,  1,    from_item_no_1,   qty_1
ord_no, item_no, line_no,  2,    from_item_no_2,   qty_2
ord_no, item_no, line_no,  3,    from_item_no_3,   qty_3
ord_no, item_no, line_no,  4,    from_item_no_4,   qty_4


-------item_No 10


-------item_No 2
```

Comment: it sounds like you need to use unpivot http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: So... your oepiklst_sql table has separate columns for each number "from_item_no_#'?  or just one column for both "from_item_no" and "qty"?

Comment: separate................

Answer (score 0):

I could do this but it is messy.

```
 select a.ord_no, a.item_no,a.line_no,1, b.from_item_no_1,b.qty_1 from oeordlin_progview a
             join oepiklst_sql b on a.ord_no = b.ord_no and a.line_no = b.line_seq_no

             WHERE a.ord_type = 'O' 
             AND a.loc = '1' 
             AND a.picked_dt IS NULL
             AND a.line_item_status = 'FRFIN' 
             and a.ord_no = 410672
             union all
select a.ord_no, a.item_no,a.line_no,2, b.from_item_no_2,b.qty_2 from oeordlin_progview a
             join oepiklst_sql b on a.ord_no = b.ord_no and a.line_no = b.line_seq_no

             WHERE a.ord_type = 'O' 
             AND a.loc = '1' 
             AND a.picked_dt IS NULL
             AND a.line_item_status = 'FRFIN' 
             and a.ord_no = 410672
             union all
select a.ord_no, a.item_no,a.line_no,3, b.from_item_no_3, b.qty_3 from oeordlin_progview a
             join oepiklst_sql b on a.ord_no = b.ord_no and a.line_no = b.line_seq_no

             WHERE a.ord_type = 'O' 
             AND a.loc = '1' 
             AND a.picked_dt IS NULL
             AND a.line_item_status = 'FRFIN' 
             and a.ord_no = 410672
              union all
 select a.ord_no, a.item_no,a.line_no,4,b.from_item_no_4,b.qty_4 from oeordlin_progview a
             join oepiklst_sql b on a.ord_no = b.ord_no and a.line_no = b.line_seq_no

             WHERE a.ord_type = 'O' 
             AND a.loc = '1' 
             AND a.picked_dt IS NULL
             AND a.line_item_status = 'FRFIN' 
             and a.ord_no = 410672
             order by line_no
```